# Grep command to find a text after the matching pattern until the space

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep

I need a command that grep command to find a text after the matching pattern until the space.

I have a line in a file

```
shell="/mix/delta/LINUX"
```

and I need the output only as `LINUX`.

The below command give the output `delta/LINUX`,

```
grep -o 'delta/[^"]*'  file.txt
```

What I need is only `LINUX`. Please let me know what to change in this to get the expected output.

Comment: Welcome to the site. How do you identify the matching line. Is it the only one containing `shell=` or the only one containing `delta/`, or is there any other criterion?

Answer (score 2):

With `grep` that supports PCRE with `-P` flag:

```bsh
grep -Po 'delta/\K[^"]*' file.txt
```

`\K` = [Keep out](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html)

---

Alternative, pipe the result to another command, e.g. `cut` or a second `grep`, e.g.

```bsh
grep -o 'delta/[^"]*'  file.txt | cut -d/ -f2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working.!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed '/delta\//!d;s_.*/__;s/"//' file
```

- `/delta\//!d` does `d`elete all lines that don't (the `!`) contain your pattern `delta/`, just in case there could be other lines in your file
- `s_.*/__` `s`ubstitutes everything upto the slash with nothing, so it gets removed
- `s/"//` finally removes the trailing double quote

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -E 's|(.*=./.*/.*/)(.*).|\2|'
```

Match and print the second group in this case `LINUX`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` and tell it to use both `/` and `"` as field separators.  e.g.

```
$ echo 'shell="/mix/delta/LINUX"' | awk -F'[/"]' '/^shell=/ {print $5}'
LINUX
```

`LINUX` is field 5 because awk counts even empty fields (i.e. the empty field between the first `"` and the first `/`, and the empty field after the final `"`)

If you don't know how long the pathname is going to be but know you're always going to be the last path element before the closing double-quote, you can use `$(NF-1)` to output the second-last field:

```
$ echo 'shell="/mix/delta/LINUX"' | awk -F'[/"]' '/^shell=/ {print $(NF-1)}'
LINUX
```